# IntervalMarkers bands not filled for negative x values

Tags: plotting

Mathematica 13.2, I am trying to plot uncertain numbers using around, with `IntervalMarkers->"Bands"` so that these bands are filled. For negative x-axis values, the bands don't fill. Can anyone help me fix this?

```
p1 = ListLinePlot[{{1, Around[2, 0.2]}, {1.5, Around[5, 0.2]}, {2, 
    Around[4, 0.2]}},
  IntervalMarkers -> "Bands", IntervalMarkersStyle -> Orange]
p2 = ListLinePlot[{{-1, Around[2, 0.2]}, {-1.5, Around[5, 0.2]}, {-2, 
    Around[4, 0.2]}},
  IntervalMarkers -> "Bands", IntervalMarkersStyle -> Orange]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add  `Reverse`.

```
Clear[p2];
p2 = ListLinePlot[{{-1, Around[2, 0.2]}, {-1.5, Around[5, 0.2]}, {-2, 
     Around[4, 0.2]}} // Reverse, IntervalMarkers -> "Bands", 
  IntervalMarkersStyle -> Orange]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. Simultaneously happy and annoyed it was so simple...